# Как узнать Bundle Identifier в mac os?

Tags: macos

Нашел команду:

```
➜  ~ mdls -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier -r SomeApp.app
SomeApp.app: could not find SomeApp.app.
```

Но там нужно ввести имя приложения, а где взять это имя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно указать путь к приложению, например `mdls -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier -r /Applications/Safari.app/` или предварительно перейти в папку приложения, например `cd /Applications/`